# Fatal error: Call to undefined method XMLReader::readInnerXML()

Tags: php, xml

I don't know why I'm getting this error. I have libxml ver 2.6.22. I've done more searching than anyone cares for. Please help.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method XMLReader::readInnerXML()

Comment: What's your PHP version?

Comment: Can you post the xml your trying to parse? That could be the problem.

Comment: @Zenox: You mean external files actually cause PHP to forget things?

Comment: Did you enable `--enable-libxml` ? or your PHP compiled with `--disable-xmlreader`?

Comment: My environment is an appserv installation- 2.5.7 for Windows

Comment: I have no issues with processing the xml in general, just the specific need I have is to take what's between a specific tag and recurse on it but as I said the readInnerXML method is said to be undefined

Comment: I'm busy trying to update my system right now ie my PHP version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`XMLReader::readInnerXML`](http://php.net/xmlreader.readinnerxml) is available as of libxml 2.6.20 and PHP 5.2.0.

As your libxml version is newer probably it is your PHP version that is outdated.

Comment: I see, thanks. I'm on PHP 5.1.6. Strange thing then: removing the () at the end of the function call removed the error msg's but the value returned was blank. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yep, still returns a blank on appserv 2.5.10 with libxml 2.6.32 and php 5.2.6

Comment: `code` function get_xml_data($xml){ //Pull certain elements

 $reader = new XMLReader();
 //$reader->open($xmlfile);
 $reader->XML($xml);

 while ($has_read = $reader->read()) {
  switch ($reader->nodeType) {
   case (XMLREADER::ELEMENT):
     $node_type = $reader->nodeType;
     echo $node_type."->";
     $node_name = $reader->name;

      if ($node_name == "gs_relay_rpc"){//I need this to work now
       echo $node_name." = ";

       $node_value = $reader->readInnerXML;
       echo $node_value."<br>";
       get_xml_data($node_value);
      }
etc

Comment: This line "get_xml_data($node_value);" is there because at the content "gs_relay_rpc" node gets built into a sql string although it is parsed in the same way as anything else. So I need the parent tag "gs_relay_rpc", to be fully processed into the sql string before the parser continues onto other nodes. Suggestions?

Comment: When I comment the recursion out and return the '()' at the end of the function call '$reader->readInnerXML', the function works and returns a string but as soon as the line goes back I get "parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in..."

Comment: Am I being a numb-skull somewhere here?

Comment: @ThapsMagne It's quite hard to debug things in the comments. Better post a separate followup question that describes the new problem and shows the code (with formatting; formatting doesn't work well in comments)

Comment: Hi, NikiC. The new problem is due to not having a top level element as described here http://www.phphaven.com/article.php?id=14

Comment: I'm trying to process the content of a node completely before parsing the rest of the document in the normal way. Is the question clearer?

Comment: How do I post a follow-up question from here?

Comment: Okay, thanks. I guess the first bit is resolved then, and hence this particular question